# Does an infinite series define an analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $S$ be either $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. Given any sequence $(a_n)$, with each $a_n\in S$, we may form a function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ whose domain is the set of points $x\in S$ such that the series is absolutely convergent, and then take $F$ to be the restriction of $f$ to the interior of its domain.

The question is: Is $F$ $S$-analytic? That is, is it the case that $F$ has a Taylor series expansion and matches its Taylor series in some neighborhood of every point in its domain?

Clearly $f$ need not be, because there are sequences such as $a_n=n!$ which converge only at $0$, so that the domain of $f$ is $\{0\}$ which is not open, and this is a necessary condition of analyticity. We can resolve this problem by considering the interior of the domain so we get an open set, which is why $F$ is defined as such. $F$ is obviously expandable as a Taylor series at $0$ (assuming $0\in\mbox{dom }F$) by definition, but at other points it is not clear what properties hold.

Comment: You can differentiate a power series term wise with the same convergence radius.

Comment: Have a look a this page: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/translating-power-series/

Comment: Yes. This is all covered in explicit detail in the first few pages of chapter 8 of Rudin. The function $F$ can be differentiated term by term, and all its derivatives have the same radius of convergence. They all diverge everywhere outside the radius of convergence. This is true for all such $F$ whether you choose $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as your domain.

Comment: @juanarroyo Thanks for the reference. Perhaps you could write an answer on how to get from the fact that infinite series are termwise differentiable, to analyticity of $F$?

Comment: I see, are you asking if $F$ has a power series expansion at every point in its domain? The answer is yes. This is because if $F$ is given by a power series in an open disk, it is complex differentiable at every point in the disk; that is, it is holomorphic in the disk. And holomorphic functions can be expressed by a power series at every point in their domain (again, valid in some open disk centered at that point). You're basically doing complex analysis at this point and unfortunately I don't know any easier proof. If you're interested I could probably sketch a proof.

Comment: If you know some multivariable calc.

Comment: @juanarroyo Unfortunately, I am not in a position to use theorems from complex analysis at this point, because these theorems are being used to build the general theory upon which complex analysis and its strong theorems are built. I'm hoping there is a direct proof, given what you said about $F$ being infinitely differentiable in an open disk.

Comment: Infinitely differentiable is not enough to prove analytic. The usual counterexample is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: The proof that $F$ is analytic at every point in the disk is usually proved in complex analysis, without any circular arguments.

Comment: And BTW it looks like the link Thomas gave has a more elementary proof.